# Posting a form to same page with URL var in standalone ios app

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm currently working on a standalone iOs iPad application. In this application i've a form i'ld like to submit to the same page with the URL var ?formsubmitted=true so then i can validate the form with coldfusion and send the mail.

The problem is that the script which i'm using to disable links from opening in safari also disables submitting the form. The script i'm using is

```
//disable links to open in safari
  (function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone");
```

Does someone know how i can tweak this script so that the form submit will work.

Without this script everything works except the link opens in safari.

---

SOLUTION

---

I found a working solution myself just by replacing the a tag, for submitting the form, with a span tag.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problem was to replace the a tag for submitting the form with a span tag.